# rails - Can't access a model that belongs_to another model

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, rails-activerecord

I have a 2 models: Project and Schedule.  Project has_one Schedule and Schedule belongs_to project.  After a project is created, one of the **employees** involved in the project will eventually create a schedule.  I am trying to create a page that shows the **employer** all of his/her projects that have a schedule.  In the schedules controller, I have tried the following code:

```
def show_incomplete_schedules_to_employers
    @schedules = Schedule.where("project.employer_id = ?", current_user.id).all
    @projects = @schedules.collect{|schedule| schedule.project}
end
```

but that returns the error:

```
ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid (PG::UndefinedTable: ERROR:  missing FROM-clause entry for table "project"
LINE 1: SELECT "schedules".* FROM "schedules"  WHERE (project.employ...
                                                  ^
: SELECT "schedules".* FROM "schedules"  WHERE (project.employer_id = 32)):
  app/controllers/schedules_controller.rb:174:in `show_incomplete_schedules_to_employers'
```

How can I access the employers schedules?

Comment: The error is saying that there is no table called `project` which is being called for in your `Schedule.where("project.employer_id = ?", current_user.id).all`...  What is the "project" in the statement supposed to be referencing?

Comment: All schedules belongs_to a project.

Comment: Right, but isn't that what your second statement `@projects = ...` is doing?

Comment: i need to tell the second statement which schedules to select.  In this case, i want al of the current_user (employer) schedules.

Comment: So what table are you trying to search employer_id on?  Schedules?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should add this to your Employer model:

```
has_many :schedules, through: :projects
```

And then access it:

```
current_user.employer.schedules
```

What do you need both `@projects` and `@schedules` for?

Comment: I don't think that would work because project would then need to have a schedule_id column, which would not make sense. I have '@schedules' and '@projects' because I need to access in the view the projects that contain the schedules.

Comment: Oh, I should mention 'employer' is a type of user, so current_user = employer (at least here)

Comment: AH, then just use current_user.schedules - `has_many :through` doesn't care where foreign_key is placed, it will work as long as association which name is passed to `through` is defined.

Answer (score 0):

From what I am surmising that you are attempting to do, I would approach the issue using joins.  Something like this:

```
def show_incomplete_schedules_to_employers
  @schedules = Schedule.joins(:projects).where("projects.employer_id = ?", current_user.id)
  @projects = @schedules.collect{ |schedule| schedule.project }
end
```

- note the plural form of `projects` in the `where` clause